# libgdx buttons in table stretching

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I want to create buttons in the corners of the screen for the controls of my game.
It used to work with just creating a skin, adding that skin to a `new ImageButton(skin)` and setting the size and position of that button to what is desired. I now use box2d and if i now set the size of the button to `(1, 1)` the height is correct but the width is always about 2/3 of the screen, no matter what i change it to.
I tried using a table and doing this:

```
    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
    table.setDebug(true);
    table.add(boostButtonn).width(1).height(1).bottom().right();
```

But I have no clue how to draw it in the corner of the screen, also the button is drawn in the middle of the screen with the correct size using this table, but the skin is stretched out of the button. Viewport width and height are 40,24 respectively

My skin and button code:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/flath-earth-ui.json"));
Button bootsButton = new ImageButton(skin);
```

And then i add it to the table

Comment: please explain your requirement in pictorial view ?

Comment: i want 1 button in the top right, 2 bottom left with some space in between them and 1 bottom right.

Comment: the buttons temselves are working (i see the red lines of the buttons from the debugger), but the skin of the button is very stretched

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in how you align or arrange your widget. Problem is why button/widget or even text is stretched and looks blurry.

Why stretched ?

Problem is in your resources. Your resources should be compatible with your viewport. If you're using small viewport then we need your resources(images and fonts) in small size.

You're using skin, that used to create `Widget`.
Skin depends on `.json` file that contains information about your Widget object and `.atlas` files having information of your image file.

You're using 40 as width of viewport then button image that used as drawable should be in range of approx. 10.

So what is solution now :

If you already have all resources ready then use some higher viewport dimension according to your resources else create create resources according to viewport.

Comment: okay thanks, but if i use a higher viewport ill have to change my entire game, cant i convert the dimensions of the skin? These resources arent mine, i downloaded them off of the git repository of libgdx. what do you mean by that the drawable should be in range of 10? 10 pixels?

Comment: Widget uses [drawable](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/Drawable.html) for drawing itself at a given rectangular size.

Comment: You can create style by yourself instead of predefined style through `.json` skin. Use that style in your Widget.

Comment: i dont fully understand, so there's no way i can use this skin without changing the width and height of the viewport?